# compiler "has no member" error with MVVM design pattern Swift

Tags: swift, generics, mvvm, protocols, associated-types

Im trying to write boiler plate code for an MVVM architecture and I'm trying to make the View interface inside my ViewModel instead of binding properties between them.
I do get a compiler error saying `Type 'V.Command' has no member 'reload'` How can I improve my code so that View is abstracted inside my ViewModel?

> Interfaces

```swift
protocol Actionable {
    associatedtype Command
    func perform(command: Command)
}

extension Actionable {
    func perform(command: Command) {}
}

protocol Rendering {
    associatedtype Model
    func render(with model: Model)
}

extension Rendering {
    func render(with dependencies: Model) {}
}

protocol VMView: Rendering, Actionable {}

protocol ViewModel {
    associatedtype Command
    associatedtype Dependencies
    associatedtype Model
}
```

> View Implementation

```swift
final class NewViewVC: UIViewController, VMView {
    typealias Model = NewViewVM<NewViewVC>.Model
    typealias Command = NewViewVM<NewViewVC>.Command
    
    func perform(command: Command) {
        print("performing \(command)")
    }
    
    func render(with model: Model) {
        print("rendering \(model)")
    }
    
    var viewModel: NewViewVM<NewViewVC>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension NewViewVC {
    static func create(dependencies: NewViewVM<NewViewVC>.Dependencies) -> NewViewVC {
        let vc = NewViewVC()
        let viewModel = NewViewVM.create(dependencies: dependencies, services: .init(), view: vc)
        vc.viewModel = viewModel
        return vc
    }
    
    static func createMock(dependencies: NewViewVM<NewViewVC>.Dependencies, services: NewViewVM<NewViewVC>.Dependencies.Services) -> NewViewVC {
        let vc = NewViewVC()
        let viewModel = NewViewVM.create(dependencies: dependencies, services: services, view: vc)
        vc.viewModel = viewModel
        return vc
    }
}
```

> ViewModel Implementation

```swift
protocol NewViewVMInterface {
    func reloadData()
}

final class NewViewVM<V: VMView>: ViewModel, NewViewVMInterface {
    
    struct Model {}
    
    enum Command {
        case start, reload
    }
    
    struct Dependencies {
        struct Services {
        }
    }
    
    private var view: V!
    private var dependencies: Dependencies!
    private var services: Dependencies.Services!
    
    static func create(dependencies: Dependencies, services: Dependencies.Services, view: V) -> NewViewVM
    where V.Model == Model, V.Command == Command {
        let viewModel = NewViewVM()
        viewModel.dependencies = dependencies
        viewModel.services = services
        viewModel.view = view
        return viewModel
    }
    
    func reloadData() {
        // fetch data
        view.perform(command: .reload) // <- Where error happens
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. A quick fix I can find is to force cast the command to `V.Command` but that's very ugly. I feel there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I put the `NewViewVMInterface` conformance to an extension  I'll be able to do something like this:

```swift
extension NewViewVM: NewViewVMInterface where V.Command == Command, V.Model == Model {
    func reloadData() {
        view.perform(command: .reload)
    }
}
```

However in my past experiences I've noticed sometime when making SDKs having protocol conformances in `extensions` results in unexpected behaviours. Im still open to any other suggestions out there.